# Application developed in vs 2008 and Hosting is godaddy .net 4.0 creating problem

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, asp.net-3.5

I have developed application in VS 2008 and trying to host on godaddy server having .net 4.0 framework and IIS7.

I am getting Internal Server error 500.

I am hosting my files under sub directory.I have set the subdirectory as Application Folder.Tried to upload files and have error.When i delete web.config and upload test aspx file it runs proper.But as i again put web.config the test files stops running and showing same error.

Please kindly help me to resolve this issue.

regards,
Sunny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that:

1. .NET 3.5 is deployed on hosting machine (should be)
2. ApplicationPool that you application is using configured to .NET 2.0 (not 4.0)

3.5 application still using 2.0 runtime, so AppPool have to be configured for 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

asp.net 3.5 applications are mostly built on stuff that are developed over the .net2.0 runtimes. So you have to set the ASP.NET version to 2.0